# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: annka.transactions index: assets_1 dup key: { : null }

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I get that error when i am trying to insert a second document into my transaction collection.

The schema is as follows

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TransactionSchema = new Schema({
amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
reference: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
}
});

TransactionSchema.index({reference:1}, {unique:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Transaction', TransactionSchema);
```

This is the code i am using to insert the document

```
var trx = new Transaction();
trx.amount = data.metadata.amount;
trx.user = data.metadata.user_id;
trx.reference = req.query.reference;
console.log(trx);
trx.save(function(err) { //save the transaction
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
     return res.render('transaction_error', {
       title: "Payment Error", message: "Oooops....An Error occured while attempting to complete the transaction. Please wait a while and try again"
     });
   }
```

`console.log(trx)` returns -

```
{
  reference: '3t3ktloj2j',
  user: 5a75a5a9c6e49c2be008b262,
  amount: 30000,
  _id: 5a8a902e67ddf65790ed5ddb
}
```

And I have a transaction in the collection already and this one has a different reference from the one in storage.

I keep getting  this error when I am trying to add a second error, not sure where its from.

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: annka.transactions index: assets_1 dup key: { : null }
```

Comment: Your collection has a unique index `assets_1`. You can check existing indexes in the shell: `db. transactions.getIndexes()`

Comment: Yes i checked and it was present but i didnt see it cos i had copied the schema of another collection and edited it for the transaction collection schema.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to save a duplicate value to a field with a **unique index** - such fields cannot store duplicate values.

For more info about unique indexes in MongoDB see : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/